# c# : find file with variable part in its name

Tags: c#, system.io.file, system.io.directory

I have a folder location corresponding to the variable "path".
In this folder, I have a lot of files, but only one called "common.build.9897ytyt4541". What I want to do is to read the content of this file, so with the following, it's working :

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "common.build.9897ytyt4541.js"));
```

The problem is, that the part between "build" and "js", change at each source code compilation, and I am getting a new hash, so I would like to replace the previous code, to have something working at each build, whatever the hash is, I thought to regex but this is not working :

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, @"common.build.*.js"));
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If this is a console application, you could call it with the new build name as an argument. Set a variable to the argument's value and then pass it to the `Path.Combine()`

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(path, @"common.build.*.js") `would list matching files, if your positive there will only be one `.First()` will return it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know you'll only find one file you can write something like this (plus error handling):

```
using System.Linq;
...
var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(path, "common.build.*.js").FirstOrDefault();
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Comment: Like this solution. I haven't tried this code.  I was wondering, what order will the files be in you use GetFiles?  Are they ordered in any way?  If they were ordered by creation / modified date, you could grab the first one in the array.  OR in this "code" case, could you just change it to order them by Creation / Modified Date and then let the FirstOrDefault grab that first file????

Comment: From the remarks section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2): "The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort method if a specific sort order is required."

Directory.GetFiles returns string[], so if you want special logic you would need to open/get additional information on each file

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use the exact filename with using `File.ReadAllText`. Instead, you need to search for the file, for this you can use `Directory.GetFiles`, for example:

```
var matches = Directory.GetFiles(path, "common.build.*.js");

if(matches.Count() == 0)
{
    //File not found
}
else if(matches.Count() > 1)
{
    //Multiple matches found
}
else
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(matches[0]);
}
```